# Pandas: Syntax in Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, syntax, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataset:

```
id window Rank    member
1    2      2        0
1    3      2        0 
2    3      1        0 
2    2      1        0
```

I want to make member to be equal to Rank when window==3. To do that, I have the following command:

```
df["member"]= df[df['window']==3]['Rank'][0]
```

However, I want to do that in a groupby statement grouping on id. The command below returns an error. It is probably a simple thing that I am missing here, but I cannot get around it how to use groupby in the above command.Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
df["member"]= df.groupby("id")[df[df['window']==3]['Rank'][0]]
```

Comment: What error is it returning? And what is your expected output, I can't follow what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `pandas.DataFrame.where` -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2],'window':[2,3,3,2],'Rank':[2,2,1,1],'member':[0,0,0,0]})
=>
    Rank  id  member  window
0     2   1       0       2
1     2   1       0       3
2     1   2       0       3
3     1   2       0       2

df['member'] = df['Rank'].where(df['window']==3, df['member'])

print(df)
=>
   Rank  id  member  window
0     2   1       0       2
1     2   1       2       3
2     1   2       1       3
3     1   2       0       2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['member'] = np.where(df['window']==3, df['Rank'], df['member'])
print (df)
   id  window  Rank  member
0   1       2     2       0
1   1       3     2       2
2   2       3     1       1
3   2       2     1       0
```

---

```
df.loc[df['window']==3, 'member'] = df['Rank']
print (df)
   id  window  Rank  member
0   1       2     2       0
1   1       3     2       2
2   2       3     1       1
3   2       2     1       0
```